# collaboration diagram versus composite structure diagram in UML 2

Tags: uml

**Composite structure diagram:**
`A diagram that shows the internal structure (including parts and connectors) of a
structured classifier or a collaboration` [from UML reference manual]

So, What is the difference between `collaboration diagram` and `composite structure diagram`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The collaboration diagram doesn't exist anymore in UML2, it has been replaced by the communication diagram.

From the UML 2.4 spec:

> Communication Diagrams focus on the interaction between Lifelines where the architecture of the internal structure and how this corresponds with the message passing is central. The sequencing of Messages is given through a sequence numbering scheme.